# How to change the color of a textView programmatically for a good contrast on Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, colors, background, contrast

i'm wondering if there is a fonction that takes an Color int and return the "Opposite color "(between Black and White)

I would use it in a recyclerView Adapter, with a background color that is customizable.

Thank you, you devs :)

Comment: The [`Palette`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/graphics/Palette) APIs may be useful.

Answer (score 0):

I quickly thought about creating my own function, but I would appreciate being aware of any official method :)

I share with you what I've written, it's working fine.

```
private int createContrastColor(int color) {

    int red = Color.red(color);
    int green = Color.green(color);
    int blue = Color.blue(color);

    if (red > 125 && green > 125 && blue > 125){
        return Color.Black;
    } else {
        return Color.White;
    }

}
```

Comment: That's not fully correct.
Suppose to have a full yellow: FFFF00, your function will set white, that is for sure wrong